# The sequence between CSS and other DOM in Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, loading

below is part of my head section in HTML. i found that the content of my page always load before the jquery.css such that the layout is so plain and return to the desired layout after  0.5 second loading time. What should I modify the code in order to avoid the plain content? is it related to the deviceready? in before, href is to the hyperlink, after that, i change it to a local file. i surprised that even a local file, it use 0.5 second to load it, instead of loading it instantly.

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", showConfirm, false);
    }

</head>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works after i change jquery mobile and jquery to latest version............

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the line that loads Cordova-2.3.0.js below the lines that load your CSS. So something like:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", showConfirm, false);
}

</head>
```